# c# printdocument

Tags: c#, printdocument, printer-properties

I am using printDocument to print from a list view. This all works fine. Originally when the print dialog opened I could use the default printer or choose another (such as adobe pdf or send to one-note). Now the dialog still displays but no matter what option I choose always prints to the default printer. I haven't intentionally made any changes but may have inadvertently changed a property or something.
Does anyone have any ideas of what I may have done?

Comment: It might help if you edit your question and post your non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
 printDialog.ShowDialog();
 printPreviewDialog1.Document.PrinterSettings = printDialog.PrinterSettings;
```